# How we create an array in oracle database tables and i need to fetch data in java

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, oracle11g, ddl

[image]
 I am creating a table with fields like id primary and contact_id(foreign key) and I want two arrays one for mail_id and one for phone numbers How can I do that?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating a `type` of *string array* :

```
SQL> create type arr_str is varray(10) of varchar2(10);
  2  /

Type created

SQL> create table ContactProperties(
  2    id         int primary key,
  3    contact_id int references contact(id),
  4    email_id   arr_str,
  5    "number"   arr_str);

Table created
```

P.S. `number` is a *reserved keyword* and must be quoted if it's used as a column name of a table.

Comment: Or there is `create type xxx as table of varchar2(n)` to lose the 10-item limit and unlock the multiset functions.